# Create a DB alias using T-SQL in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to create a Database alias for many of the DBs. I wonder if there is a T-sql that can let me do it. I have not found anything about this.

Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. SQL2005 introduced synonyms but these can't be used as database aliases.